# Jquery autocomplete is not working in bootstrap model

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using jquery autocomple inside bootstrap model but it's not appearing correctly.However if I use it without model it's working fine.I think it's CSS problem but I do not know what it is.

Thanks,

Comment: hi Xchamp, we need to see your code. please give us a [mcve] of what you have currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something z-index and position relative problem. Please try below code.Please edit your question and add the code you are using if it does not help.

```css
 .ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$("#autocomplete")
    .appendTo($("#divWhereAutoCompleteIsEmbeded"))
    .autocomplete({
    source: function (query, result) {
        //some fetching routine
        },
    appendTo: $("#divWhereAutoCompleteIsEmbeded"),
    minLength: 2
});
```